# Regular expression that requires quotes if spaces are present

Tags: regex, ruby

I am trying to come up with a regular expression that will match a string that contains substrings.  If the substring contains spaces then it needs to be quoted.

I want to match things like:

```
model.field:if(eql?"This String")
```

Note that "This String" can be any string.  However, it can only include letters, numbers, and underscores. If there are no spaces then it really doesn't require the quotes.  So,

```
model.field:if(eql?ThisString)
```

is a valid match.

Comment: You need to (edit to) enclose your string in single quotes so that it is a valid string object. Also, I if you indent it 4 spaces it will be highlighted. You should also specify the substring that must be matched (presumably `"This String"`).

Answer (score 0):

```
str = 'model.field:if(eql?"This String")'
  #=> "model.field:if(eql?\"This String\")" 
substring = '"This String"'
  #=> "\"This String\""
```

```
r = /#{substring}/
  #=> /"This String"/
str.match?(r)
  #=> true
```

See [String#match?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-match-3F). If you wish to return the entire string if there is a match (else `nil`), use the following:

```
r = /.*#{substring}.*/
  #=> /.*"This String".*/ 
str[r]
  #=> "model.field:if(eql?\"This String\")"
```

See [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D). This regular expression reads, "match zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by the substring (`"This String"`), followed by zero or more characters (`.*`).

Notice that

```
str = 'model.field:if(eql?"This String")'
```

is the same as

```
str = "model.field:if(eql?\"This String\")"
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem because I don't know what {substring} is in advance.  I would want to capture that as a match group.  Also model.field is variable also. Thanks.